# Updates revert to previous entry in Access Database

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, updates

I tried to see if I could find an answer to this, but I haven't yet. At my job, we have this Access database that was around long before I had the job. There is a form that's used to update information and it's on a shared system. Whenever an update to this specific table is made, the update will sometimes revert to what it was previously without anyone going in and changing it. From what I can tell, it only happens with a few fields. Still, it is quite annoying to me and the people who have to update this information.

I just want to know what could cause this to happen in an Access database. If I can get an idea of what could cause this, I should be able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way updates can "revert" in Access is if the update is cancelled or a transaction (in code) is rolled back. Or if a user of the same record stores (parts of) the old information and writes this back after another user has made an update and this concurrency issue is handled silently by coded.

So you will have to study the code that handles the update in that form.

Comment: "Or if a user of the same record stores (parts of) the old information and writes this back after another user has made an update and this concurrency issue is handled silently by code" -- That would be my guess too.